# Enable/Disable button based on the stored procedure return value

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 button in the .aspx page;Time In & Time Out. In the page load, based on the last action performed by the user, I want to enable/disable that button. Am checking in the table whether user has performed a time in or time out entry. A procedure returns 0 if timed in and 1 if timed out. If he/she made a time in, time in should be disabled till next day for that particular user. Only time out should be in the enabled mode.How to achieve this?

In the page load, i have the following code for displaying appropriate button for the user.

```
        string userId = string.Empty;
        if (Session["UserId"] != null)
            userId = Session["UserId"].ToString();

        byte status = GetLatestCheckInOutStatusByUser(userId);

        if (status == 0)
        {
            OutButton.ImageUrl = @"~/Styles/Images/ClockOut.PNG";
            InButton.ImageUrl = @"~/Styles/Images/ClockInFade.PNG";
            //InButton.Enabled = false;
            //OutButton.Enabled = true;


        }
        else if (status == 1)
        {
            InButton.ImageUrl = @"~/Styles/Images/ClockIn.JPG";            
            OutButton.ImageUrl = @"~/Styles/Images/ClockOutFade.PNG";
            //InButton.Enabled = true;
            //OutButton.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: Please add it in question for clarity.

Comment: so what is the issue ?Code seems to be fine.

Comment: They are simply images. I want to disable the button click.

Comment: @Shyju How about hiding the button itself when not used?

Comment: @abramlimpin  No, I want both the buttons on screen. If it's disabled, disabled button image is showing. But still it's causing postback that am unable to stop.

Comment: you have commented the code to disable the button.... you can disable button using jquery also

Comment: Why you commented those lines ? `//InButton.Enabled = false;`

Comment: @ArunChandranC, even if i enabled, still it's raising that click event.

Comment: Show the code of buttons.

Comment: Problem solved :) Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: @Shyju How you resolve the problem ? post as answer